# How to read empty lines in .bat file and the variables are placed inside %xyz%

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cd /d D:\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "var=v3 "
set "file=Rev.bat"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "%var%" Rev.bat') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set /a sequence=%%~j+1
)
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!
    echo(!line!>>!file!
 )
```

I tried this code it doesn't find the string

Comment: @Gerhard I put the code. I hope it easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so if I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
@echo off
cd /d D:\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=rev.bat"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "%~1" rev.bat') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set /a sequence=%%~j+1
)
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!
    echo(!line!>>!file!
 )
```

Explanation. We get the file content, using `find` to assign row id's Then we do search and replace and simply remove the row id's. Then write back everything to the file including the updated version.

note, you need to run the script with a parameter, i.e. `script.cmd v3`

Edit. to do more than one variable at a time by request, do:

```
@echo off
cd /d D:\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:Begin
set /p "var=enter variable to replace [.ie v1, v2, v3]: "
set "file=rev.bat"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "%var%" rev.bat') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set /a sequence=%%~j+1
)
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!
    echo(!line!>>!file!
 )
```

Comment: no, don't replace anything in the code. you need to run the code from a `cmd` prompt as it is now, then give it a parameter i.e `script.cmd v3` or `script.cmd v2` etc. if you want to auto increment more than one, then open `cmd` and run `for %i in (v1 v2 v3) do call script.cmd %i`